# SSL Handshake exception after ChangeCipherSpec

Tags: ssl, wireshark

I have a server and client application which is connecting and getting the data but since 1 week i'm getting SSL handshake exception following are debug step done to fix.

1. Install intermediate and CA certificate to the server.
2. Change order of ciphers with the server, as server always accepts "Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x006b)"
   got this from wireshark pcap file.
3. Following the error that comes on wireshark.

   ```
   ajp-bio-8009-exec-3, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal,
   [2016-11-07 01:48:53.110] [Thread Id: 152] handshake_failure
   [2016-11-07 01:48:53.110] [Thread Id: 152] %% Invalidated:  [Session-7, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256]
   ```
4. Server and client accepts only TLS1.2

Comment: Your post needs editing.  Don't post a question in a code block.  Please refer to: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And make the effort to complete the 2-minute site tour as well.

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code. Edit rejected.